# Is it somehow possible to get a native Windows menu bar in NW.js applications, or to at least style them?

Tags: css, customization, chromium, styling, nwjs

I've followed this: https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Menu/#menu

The result is a very Chromium-looking menu. The items just look... nothing like how I think of Windows menu items. (Even though there are these days a million different styles of them in this FrankensteinOS...)

Is this it? I have to use whatever Chromium thinks is a good looking menu? I cannot style them with CSS or something, at least? For example, if I want them to be "dark mode" instead of bright white? I guess I could implement my own custom Canvas-based pixel-perfect menu, but that's both a ton of work and also will never feel native or quite as "responsive".

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you pointed to is for using the Native OS Menu. This will be different on Linux, OSX, and Windows, and will match the native placement and interactions for that system, including keyboard navigation. Similar to how the minimize/maximize/restore/close buttons are built in and differ on each OS.

You can add your own markup and styling to create a custom menu if you like though, and it will look and act the same on every OS. Similarly, you can create your own markup and styles for the min/max/restore/close buttons, and title bar.

- https://github.com/nwutils/frameless-example

If you're not confident in HTML/CSS enough to make a responsive menu yourself, you can use frameworks, like Bootstrap, which come responsive with menu styling out of the box.

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: This answer misrepresents the situation regarding native menus on Windows. Using the menu API results in menus that don't support standard keyboard navigation (e.g. F10) and don't have standard hover behaviour when moving between open menus.